# Oracle display timestamp as military time

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have a timestamp column in one of my tables. I am doing the following and its displayed as 12.00.00.100000 AM but when the time passes 12AM its displayed in military time as I want it.

How can I display the date as military time 12AM time as 00:00:00.100000

```
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF';

SEQ_NUM    DT
1    01-JAN-22 12.00.00.000000 AM
2    01-JAN-22 12.05.00.100000 AM
3    01-JAN-22 12.10.00.200000 AM
4    01-JAN-22 12.15.00.300000 AM
5    01-JAN-22 12.20.00.400000 AM
6    01-JAN-22 12.25.00.500000 AM
7    01-JAN-22 12.30.00.600000 AM
8    01-JAN-22 12.35.00.700000 AM
9    01-JAN-22 12.40.00.800000 AM
10    01-JAN-22 12.45.00.900000 AM
11    01-JAN-22 12.50.00.000000 AM
12    01-JAN-22 12.55.00.100000 AM
13    01-JAN-22 01.00.00.200000 AM
14    01-JAN-22 01.05.00.300000 AM
```

Comment: Is your column TIMESTAMP, or TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE? From your output it seems to be the former so set `SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` instead (or as well).

Comment: Do you mean by "military time" also UTC time? `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF` is format according to ISO-8601860. If I remember correctly to my military service, the [military time](https://militarybenefits.info/military-time/) was completely different.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It depends on the military. If you use [DTG notation](https://special-ops.org/military-time-military-date-time-group-explained/) then the format is `DDHH24MI(Z)MONYY`.

Comment: My column is is just plain timestamp.  CREATE TABLE t3 (
seq_num NUMBER  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
dt TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data type is `TIMESTAMP` then use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF';
```

If your data type is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` then use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR';
```

or

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM';
```

---

However, any user can change their own session parameters at any time so if you want a particular format then you are better to change from outputting a `TIMESTAMP` to outputting a string containing the value in the given format using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT seq_num,
       TO_CHAR(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AS dt
FROM   table_name;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=efbc89d0a8b19faafa7483493d862b87)*

Comment: MTO  thanks for responding. I'm using a plain timestamp and testing on livesql. I prefer not to have my users use the mask if they don't have too. My table declaration  CREATE TABLE t3 (
seq_num NUMBER  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
dt TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have a plain `TIMESTAMP` column, not a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column. (Or it could be `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`, if your session is set up as UTC/GMT.)

You are setting `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT`, but that applies to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, not plain `TIMESTAMP`.

If you set the relevant NLS parameter instead (without the `_TZ` part):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF';
```

then you get:

| SEQ_NUM | DT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 00:05:00.100000 |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 00:10:00.200000 |
| 4 | 2022-01-01 00:15:00.300000 |
| 5 | 2022-01-01 00:20:00.400000 |
| 6 | 2022-01-01 00:25:00.500000 |
| 7 | 2022-01-01 00:30:00.600000 |
| 8 | 2022-01-01 00:35:00.700000 |
| 9 | 2022-01-01 00:40:00.800000 |
| 10 | 2022-01-01 00:45:00.900000 |
| 11 | 2022-01-01 00:50:01.000000 |
| 12 | 2022-01-01 00:55:01.100000 |
| 13 | 2022-01-01 01:00:01.200000 |
| 14 | 2022-01-01 01:05:01.300000 |

db<>fiddle [with plain TIMESTAMP](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=36b1edb3f3441a456be69c01a6a57e67), or [with TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=36b1edb3f3441a456be69c01a6a57e67), which gets the same output as the session time zone is GMT.

Or you can use `to_char()` with the same format mask, so you aren't relying on session NLS settings.

Comment: Alex thanks for responding. I'm testing  on livesql. CREATE TABLE t3 (
seq_num NUMBER  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
dt TIMESTAMP)

Comment: @Pugzly - that's what I assume; just include local to cover that possibility. It's the same NLS setting either way though. Or the same format mask whichever timestamp variant is used. (I've skipped over exactly what you mean by 'military time', and whether that implies conversion to UTC or additional formatting; and kind of assumed the looser and simpler '24-hour clock' meaning', [as here](https://military.onlineclock.net/chart/).)

Comment: Alex thanks for your help and expertise everything is all good now